# Rendering different controller view in sitelayout in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I have a layout which has a sidebar. Inside sidebar, there is a block for displaying list of categories. I have called a controller (fetches list of categories) to be rendered inside this block. Here is how my sidebar looks like:

Here is my main layout file containing sidebar:

```
<!--  siteLayout.html.twig   -->
<div id="sidebar">
  {% block sidebarBlock1 %}
    {% render "TestBundle:Index:categoryList" %}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**TestBundle:Index:categoryList** fetches list of categories from database and returns as below:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/category/1">Category 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/category/2">Category 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

All my other views extends siteLayout.html.twig. What i want is that when users loads this url "/category/1" i want to add css class to li tag.

For example if someone clicks /category/1 then the output should be

```
<li class="active">.......</li>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li  {% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'category_view' %} 
         class="active" 
     {% endif %}>
</li>
```

Check route and set class if route matches your category route. Replace category_view with the route name of /category

Answer (score 0):

```
   {%if app.request.server.get('REQUEST_URI')== path('viewCategoryItems', {'slugName': category.slugName})%} class="active"{%endif%}
```

This worked for me